# How to install pip globally on Ubuntu 20.04, so that all users can use it the same way?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip

I set up a VMware machine under Windows 10, running Ubuntu 20.04.

The first thing I did after the installation was to install pip:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I then did:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip3
```

to which I got an error saying that the package `pip3` doesn't exist. So I did:

```
sudo pip3 install --updgrade pip
```

which finished and installed pip 21.0.1

Now if I run pip3 with sudo, I have to type `sudo pip3`, but for a non-root user I have to use `pip` insted of `pip3`

`sudo pip3 --version` and `sudo pip --version` and `pip --version` return the same:

```
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

But `pip3 --version` returns: `bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory`

I just want to use the command pip3 both with and without root privilige and I don't understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory

This is because `bash` still remembers where it saw `pip3` last time and the place was changed from `/usr/bin/pip3` to `/usr/local/bin/pip3`. To clear its memory run `hash -r`. See command `hash` in [`bash` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: Thanks! After running `hash -r` from what I understand, I can now use  `pip` or `pip3` interchangeably, because both return the same version and path when I check with `--version`. Is this a problem, or is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: **cache invalidation** and naming things."